# How to scrape CME using power query.?

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, automation, powerquery

I am trying to pull the data from the table which is on the CME website. but I cant scrape it I am newbie please help.

the link for the table from where I am trying to get data is given below,

https://www.cmegroup.com/market-data/volume-open-interest/fx-volume.html

Comment: There's a download data option. Is there a reason that isn't acceptable?

Comment: @user:765226 yeah I know there is an option to download excel. whole excel is not of my interest I want to scrape only the for future currencies like AUD, JPY, CHF. so I want to make automation whenever the data gets updated on the website I can simply run the script to get my desired data instead of pulling the data manually and saving it in excel.